Drawing constraint sets in standard form
Is there any way to draw a heart-shaped constraint set using the intersection of simple curves (e.g. lines) to form a standard constraint set?
$$\begin{aligned}
&{\underset {x}{\operatorname {minimize} }} && f(x) \\
&\operatorname {subject\;to} && g_{i}(x) \leq 0, \quad i = 1, \dots, m 
\end{aligned}$$
Is there any result saying it is impossible?
Another example is a circle without a sector constraint set.

Does "heart-shaped" mean a cardioid?
Here's the second part:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dk21bj52ct

In Cartesian coordinates:
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2 &\le 1 \\
\frac{\pi}{8} \le \text{atan2}(y,x) &\le \frac{15\pi}{8}
\end{align}
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Using this Python snippet
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.1, 1.1, 400)
y = np.linspace(-1.1, 1.1, 400)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

region_condition = X**2 + Y**2 <= 1 & (np.pi/8 <= np.arctan2(Y, X)) & (np.arctan2(Y, X) <= 15*np.pi/8)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.contourf(X, Y, region_condition, levels=[-1, 0, 1], colors=['white', 'blue'], alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()

I get this shape:

